# Video playback problems in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, video-streaming

I have downloaded sample code from Apple Center.I also have gone through following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370245/iphone-video-playback-coding

Let me explain what my problem is:

- I executes downloaded code first time
- Video runs perfectly without any blinking (smooth playing)
- I press done button on top-left corner of media player.
- video is stopped now.
- Now I again start video play
- Video isn't playing as good as previously.

Now, I have implemented the same code - for playing video - in my application. Where am I making mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have seen this issue when playing video on the simulator when using a custom overlay . It works for me on the actual device.

Here is some discussion about video playback differences between the two:
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=6898360

Have you tested on the actual device?